# How to set cooldowns depends on how many "suitcases" the user have?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Im doing a economy commands that you can buy an item call "suitcase"
So if you have this item, you can use `work` command

So lets say `User A` has `n` suicase
So the cooldowns look like this:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(n,3600,commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(ctx):
    ...
```

Is this possible? How?

Since the `ctx` thingy is after the cooldowns thingy so I cant get the author's data

Answer (score 2):

You can always run a function after where you define the function using `ctx`.

You should have a look at writing a custom [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) such as the example below:

```py
async def has_suitcase(ctx):
    return True # replace this with your logic

@bot.command()
@commands.check(has_suitcase)
async def work(ctx):
    ...
```

Comment: That a good answer but not answering `cooldowns depends on how many “suitcases”` I guess? Maybe should combine custom check and custom cooldown.

Comment: @Kouheng cooldowns would be a normal function within the logic to get the time, that's why I never included it as OP may be using sql or nosql and that

Comment: @Mortis_666 store the datetime of the first time, every time the user executes that check, check the database and compare the datetime. If total_seconds() of a `datetime` difference is bigger to or equal to the minimum of total_seconds required then return True, else ctx.send("Cool down")